# Homeomorphism : one to one relation between every open (of both topological spaces)?

Tags: general-topology

I'd like to understand what is meant by "a homeomorphism preserve the topological structure".

If we have two topological spaces $(A, \mathscr O _A)$ and $(B,\mathscr O _B)$  and $f$ is a homeomorphism between both, does that mean that to every open $U\in \mathscr O _B$ we can assign a *corresponding* open $U' \in \mathscr O _A$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Note that if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a continuous map, then $f^{-1}$ being continuous is equivalent to $f$ being an open map. In other words, if $f$ is homeomorphic, then not only is the preimage of every open set open in the domain (continuity), but the image of every open set is open in the codomain too. Furthermore, the bijectivity of $f$ tells you that $$ff^{-1}(U') = U'$$ and $$f^{-1}f(U) = U$$

Comment: So that means, if $\mathscr O _A$ and $\mathscr O _B$ are discrete topologies then both topologies should have the same cardinality ? (the same number of open sets)

Comment: Not only if they're discrete topologies, but any topologies. Homeomorphic spaces are indistinguishable (in the category of topological spaces).